# SWIFT: Short cut for accessing objects?

Tags: performance, swift, object, shortcut

When setting parameters to objects, I often need to access the same object several times like:

```
monster.physicsBody?.dynamic = true 
monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile
monster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
```

Is there any shortcut in SWIFT to make it shorter but same performance or even better? In VB there is something like

```
With monster.physicsBody
   .dynamic = ...
End With
```

When assigning to new variable I get a copy, so I could not change the original value. Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you just make a new variable and set it up then set monster equal to that variable to change monster itself?

Comment: If you find that it is always/very often the same parameters you are changing, it may be worth writing a method to update them so you could call it more easily and trim down your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no anything like `With` in Swift. You can use `if let` with one letter variable to make it as short as possible. Also if `categoryBitMask` is of type `PhysicsCategory` you can use just `.Monster`, etc.

```
if let b = monster.physicsBody {
  b.dynamic = true 
  b.categoryBitMask = .Monster
  b.contactTestBitMask = .Projectile
  b.collisionBitMask = .None
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this

```
var physPath = monster.physicsBody

physPath.dynamic = true 
physPath.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
physPath.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile
physPath.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
```

to access the same object.

Comment: That doesn't really address the topic OP asked about. They are asking if there is a shortcut to avoid having to type `physPath.property` every time as there is with VB. As far as the answer to that question, I'm not sure, maybe someone with a more in depth knowledge of Swift does.